# Problematic quotations

Tags: shell-script, ksh, quoting

```
#!/bin/ksh
typeset FILE_SIZE1=$(stat -f '%z' test.txt);
typeset -r BK_STATARGS="-f '%z'"
typeset FILE_SIZE2=$(stat ${BK_STATARGS} test.txt);
echo without arg var ${FILE_SIZE1}
echo with arg var... ${FILE_SIZE2}
```

Yields....

```
without arg var 216
with arg var... '216'
```

Maybe I'm missing the obvious but I can't figure out a fix.  I've tried all sorts of things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BK_STATARGS` is a variable whose content is the 7-character string `-f '%z'`. First, let's see what happens in the command

```
stat "${BK_STATARGS}" test.txt
```

The shell first parses the command into a syntax tree, which here consists of a single simple command, with three tokens: `stat`, the result of the expansion of `${BK_STATARGS}`, and `test.txt`. Then the shell expands the value of the variable, in order to determine the second word, which is `-f '%z'` (that same 7-character string). Finally the shell executes the command in the first word, passing the subsequent words as command line arguments, so `stat` is executed with two arguments `-f '%z'` and `test.txt`.

Let's now turn to the more complex command

```
stat ${BK_STATARGS} test.txt
```

The processing is the same until the expansion of the value of the variable. Since the variable substitution is not in double quotes, its value is treated as a whitespace-separated list of words. There is one whitespace character in the string, so it is split into two words, and `stat` receives three arguments: `-f`, `'%z'` and `test.txt`.

The single quotes are part of shell syntax: they are recognized at the parsing stage. They have no special meaning when they're in a string, even if the string gets split after variable expansion.

Since `%` and `z` are not special characters, you don't need to quote them:

```
typeset -r BK_STATARGS="-f %z"
typeset FILE_SIZE2=$(stat ${BK_STATARGS} test.txt)
```

In general, to pass multiple arguments to a command, you need to use an array instead of a string.

```
typeset -a BK_STATARGS; BK_STATARGS=(-f '%z')
typeset FILE_SIZE2=$(stat "${BK_STATARGS[@]}" test.txt)
```

`"${BK_STATARGS[@]}"` is the syntax to expand an array into its list of elements. Even though it looks like a single word due to the double quotes, it's actually split into multiple words due to the `[@]` subscript, working like `"$@`.